# Using Mysql function in java spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot

Got a little problem with custom query in my repository:

```
@Query("select v from Visit v where YEARWEEK('date') = YEARWEEK(curdate())")
```

Error shows before YEARWEEK('date') opening bracket:

```
<expression>, <operator>, AND, GROUP, HAVING, IS, OR or ORDER expected, got '('
```

Comment: Also `SELECT v FROM Visit v` looks ambiguous or a typo.  Perhaps `SELECT v.* FROM Visit v`?  And the quotes around `'date'` would usually represent strings, do you mean backticks `?

Comment: Spring Data uses JPQL, not SQL (unless you specify it explicitly) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have two options:

For HQL you need following:

```
@Query("select * from Visit v where YEARWEEK('v.date') = YEARWEEK(curdate())")
```

You can have native query also, in that case you need following (not the best way for Spring applications, though can be used for some cases)

```
@Query(value = "select * from Visit where YEARWEEK('date') = YEARWEEK(curdate())", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Solved.

Answer (score 3):

> The @Query annotation allows to execute native queries by setting the nativeQuery flag to true.

```
@Query("select v from Visit v where YEARWEEK('date') = YEARWEEK(curdate())", nativeQuery = true)
```

see spring-data docs `Using @Query` [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Solved.