# query at postgres HOW in Spring JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

there is here such a request:

```
select *
from Organization t
where (t.inn,t.kpp) IN(('000000','00000'),('1111111','111111'));
```

How make this Query in Spring Data JPA.
I tried like this:

```
@Query(value =
"SELECT t" +
    " FROM Organization t" +
    " WHERE (t.inn, t.kpp) IN :innKppList")
```

List findOrganizationsByInnKpp(@Param("innKppList") Map innKppList);

But it does not work...

Comment: Jpql 'in' is for a single value in a collection

Comment: also , refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/48540115/493216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can split up your map into two lists this will work

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Organization t WHERE t.inn IN ?1 AND t.kpp IN ?2")
Set<Organization> findByInnAndKpp(List<String> inn, List<String> kpp);
```